# php shift array element to first if a single condition is met

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have an array of image urls.

Only one of them can be `main_image`.

I need to put this main image at beginning of the array.

Here's what I am trying:

```
$r_img_main = 'main_image.png';
foreach ($r_images_arr as $r_image) {
    $is_main = $r_image === $r_img_main ? true : false;
    $img_class = $is_main ? 'main_img' : 'regular_img';
    $img_html .= '<a href="' . $r_image . '" target="_blank"><img src="' . $r_image . '" height="70" width="70" class="'.$img_class.'"></a>';
}
```

I am rendering these images to html.

I need the `main image` to be rendered at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array-search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to find the main img position and remove it from the original array. Afterward, render the main img first and then the rest of the array:

```
// find the position of the main img and render it
$pos = array_search('main_image.png', $r_images_arr); 
$img_html .= '<a href="main_image.png" target="_blank"><img src="main_image.png" height="70" width="70" class="main_img"></a>';

// remove the main ing from the array
unset($r_images_arr[$pos]);

// render all the rest after
foreach ($r_images_arr as $r_image) {
    $img_html .= '<a href="' . $r_image . '" target="_blank"><img src="' . $r_image . '" height="70" width="70" class="regular_img"></a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `array_search` to find the main image and use unset the array element.
2. use `array_unshift` to insert main image on first position

   ```
   $a = ['1.png', '2.png', 'main.png', '4.png'];
   $main = 'main.png';
   unset($a[array_search($main, $a)]);
   array_unshift($a,$main);
   ```

3.Now you have the main image on position first, you can use foreach to render it

```
foreach($a as $k => $v){
   ($k == 0) ? (RENDER MAIN IMAGE) : 'RENDER REST IMAGES';
}
```